# How do I replicate a pandas function in MySQL?

Tags: python, odbc, ssms

Im new to SQL and trying to unlearn what I know in python. I have a script where I connect to the odbc of SSMS to work with data in Python:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
#odbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=PMZZ315\RION;'
                      'Database=Warehouse;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT [LetId],[StreetAddressLine1],[CompanyName] FROM Dim.Let", conn)
df

df.head()
#print(df.columns)


# Select duplicate rows except first occurrence based on all columns
duplicateRowsDF = df[df.duplicated(['CompanyName','StreetAddressLine1'])]

#print("Duplicate Rows except first occurrence based on all columns are :")
print(duplicateRowsDF)
duplicateRowsDF.to_csv("duplicateRowsDFodbc.csv")
```

What function in SQL can substitute the df.duplicated function? All I am trying to do is detect duplicate records ignoring the first instance if the company name and street address are repeated

Reprex of output dataset:

```
LetId   StreetAddressLine1           CompanyName
32  1451 West Brimson View Court    Palmer 
405 1808 North Lonion Ave           Ozark 
465 4223 Monty Hwy              Alabama
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is only provided by columns in the data.  There is no "first" without an ordering.  Let me assume that `letid` defines the ordering.

The canonical way in SQL uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by CompanyName, StreetAddressLine1 order by letid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It says Incorrect syntax near ')'. where row_number() is given

Comment: @user10001876 . . . There is nothing obviously wrong with the syntax.